# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't boot, Sony Vaio VGN-NW11S

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, freeze, vaio

I've set up Ubuntu 14.04 on a Sony Vaio (VGN-NW11S), dual boot with Windows 7.
The computer is approx. 4 years old.
It worked fine for 1 week or so, but since a few days it doesn't boot any more.
I assume it was some update causing the problem, because nothing else changed.
Grub is still working, so i can choose Ubuntu, but i get a lot of errors of the form:

```
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata1.00: error: { UNC}
end_request I/O error, dev sda, sector ...(some number)
```

One says corrupt memory
then it gets stuck at the Ubuntu loading screen.
I tried different Kernel versions + recovery modes, they all produce the same errors.
Despite the errors, i can access the recovery mode.
Does that mean my boot sectors are corrupted?

Besides that, Windows 7 is booting without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

*Three* possible problems:

1. Memory
2. HD controller (or driver)
3. HD itself.

*Two* possible solutions:

1. As grub is still working, do the MemTest86+
2. Take the HD out of the computer, (that way you bypass the HD controller + driver) put it in an enclosure and hook it up to someone elses Linux PC and run fsck *without mounting the drive!*

If you need exact commands, report back here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I did the MemTest, but there everything seems to be ok.
I also ran fsck in the recovery mode.
I'll try what you suggested

Comment: Upvoting my answer would be nice...  How are things now??? ;-)